# Sending few values at the same time over bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I am working on a Bluetooth based application and I am having problems when I try to send data from the iPhone to the other device.

I have no problem when I have to send just one value, using something like this:

```
- (void)sendData:(NSInteger)mel {
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&mel length:sizeof(mel)];
    [self.myDevice writeValue:myData forCharacteristic:self.myCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
}
```

But, for some characteristics I need send 2 or more values at the same time (for example in this case, variable mel and another one) but I haven’t been able yet to do it.

Does somebody know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

What I tried to send two values is

```
unsigned char bytes[] = {mel, interval};
NSMutableData *myData = [NSMutableData new];
[myData appendBytes:&bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
[self.myDevice writeValue:myData forCharacteristic:self.myCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
```

But this works like if the second value didn't exist

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and explain what issue you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated the question with what I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `sizeof(bytes)` to get the number of bytes in the array. It's simply going to return `4` since that is the size of a `char *`.

One options would be to use `sizeof(mel) + sizeof(interval)` instead of `sizeof(bytes)`.